# RuntimeError: Output 0 of AliasBackward0 is a view and its base or another view of its base has been modified inplace

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, torchvision

I'm trying to implement a custom loss. However, the custom loss requires me to transform the output of my network. For that I'm using MONAI's [NormalizeIntensity](https://docs.monai.io/en/stable/_modules/monai/transforms/intensity/array.html#NormalizeIntensity). However, I'm getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Output 0 of AliasBackward0 is a view and its base or another view of its base has been modified inplace. This view is the output of a function that returns multiple views. Such functions do not allow the output views to be modified inplace. You should replace the inplace operation by an out-of-place one.
```

I believe the error comes from line:

```
img[slices] = (img[slices] - _sub) / _div
```

Essentially, img has gradients since it's the output of my network. I need to transform img because of my custom loss. Then I the transformed img in the criterion... I can't detach the transformed img because I need gradients of img to flow back to the network.

Does this have a solution?? Can the problem be elsewhere? Maybe my network has problems?